# How do I generate standardized model instance template code in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm developing a website in Django where many of the sites' models' instances are presented to the user in a standardized format on many different pages. I'd like to avoid redundancy in the template coding by creating standard model instance template code then just inserting it each page where a model instance needs to be displayed.

What is the best practice for creating standardized instance display code, then adding it into many different pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of accomplishing this...

One is to use an include tag and pass your object to the template. Another, similar approach is to create a template tag to render the object, which is useful if you need to do some extra processing in Python before doing the rendering.

Yet another way is to add an instance method to your model to render itself to HTML (or some other format), much the same way a form instance has `.as_ul` or `.as_p` that you can call in your template where needed.

Neither way is right or wrong, it just depends on what you're most comfortable with stylistically and what's most efficient for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think the adding an instance-to-html rending method added to the model class would work well for my current use case. Can I call the function directly from the instance object in a template, or do I need to preload the function's output into the template's context?

Comment: You should be able to reference the method directly in the template as: `your_model_instance.as_html`